# Why does rigid body physics not work in objects created by an object instancer? (Animation nodes)

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, animation-nodes, rigidbody

Simple setup:
[image]

When I've played an animation, an instanced cube has stayed put: 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are setting their locations explicitly using the *Transforms Output* node, so the simulation obviously won't take effect. Second, objects need to be linked to the `RigidBodyWorld` collection, so you can use the following expression:

```py
[collection.objects.link(obj) for obj in objects if obj.name not in collection.objects]
```

So, your node tree should be as follows:

[image: Node Tree]

Comment: It seems that it's called "Object Group Input" node in 2.0.4 version of animation nodes. After linking simulation works even with transformation. Why did you think this could not work with transformation?

Comment: @OleksiyPlotnyts'kyy Ah, I didn't realize you were using 2.7x. I didn't think it would work because the objects will have their locations overwritten by the transform output node. Maybe I am missing something. So this answer solved your problem? At least in the general sense?

Answer (score -1):

Now (AN 2.2.1) it is even simplier: [image: add objects to rigid body world animation nodes]

Comment: Your answere is not helping the user in any way , please add more detail

Comment: You should add these thing in comments instead of awnseres

Comment: okay, sorry. I am new here and I thought it is obvious. This node puts objects to rigid body world. Doing the same as expression node above

Comment: also I can`t post comment to1st answer. 50 reputation needed

Comment: Chill bro just don repeat